# Почему getParcelableArrayList() возвращает null в место list

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть класс Film

```
 public class Film implements Parcelable{
private String filmName;
private String filmImage;
private String filmDate;

public Film(String filmName, String filmImage, String filmDate) {
    this.filmName = filmName;
    this.filmImage = filmImage;
    this.filmDate = filmDate;
}

public String getFilmName() {
    return filmName;
}

public String getFilmImage() {
    return filmImage;
}

public String getFilmDate() {
    return filmDate;
}

private Film(Parcel in) {
    filmName = in.readString();
    filmImage = in.readString();
    filmDate = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<Film> CREATOR = new Creator<Film>() {
    @Override
    public Film createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Film(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Film[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Film[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(filmName);
    parcel.writeString(filmImage);
    parcel.writeString(filmDate);
}
}
```

Пытаюсь передать ArrayList из одного фрагмента в другой вызовом

```
mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,    FilmsFragment.newInstance(mFilmList,"DC Films")).addToBackStack("choose").commit();
```

в OnClick 
вот метод newInstance

```
     public static FilmsFragment newInstance(ArrayList<Film> filmList, String title) {
    FilmsFragment fragment = new FilmsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelableArrayList(ARG_PARAM_FILMS, filmList);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM_FILMS, title);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

получаю так в OnCreate

```
 if (getArguments() != null) {
        mFilmList = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(ARG_PARAM_FILMS);
        mTitle = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM_TITLE);
    }
```

но после

> getParcelableArrayList()

и

> getString()

получаю null.
при передаче все норм, в предыдущем фрагменте, а вот после получения из getArguments получаю null. В чем ошибка, в реализации Parcelable?

Comment: Вы помещаете аргументы во фрагмент по одному тегу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже что вы перепутали ключи параметров. В `newInstance` вместо

```
args.putString(ARG_PARAM_FILMS, title);
```

должно быть

```
args.putString(ARG_PARAM_TITLE, title);
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, писал код в 5 утра, мозг уже не варил, оочень глупая ошибка.